# Slim 3 Framework - Fatal Error on setStatus

Tags: php, rest, slim

I just installed slim through composer and I'm trying to build a simple REST API.

My current code is the following:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->get('/getPoiInitialList', function ($request, $response, $args) {

//$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$app = new \Slim\App(); 

try 
{
    $db = getDB();

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wikivoyage_pois LIMIT 50");
    $sth->execute();

    $poiList = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if($poiList) {
        $app->response->setStatus(200);
        $app->response()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode($poiList);
        $db = null;
    } else {
        throw new PDOException('No records found.');
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $app->response()->setStatus(404);
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}

});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

I had some Slim not found errors that I was able to pass, but now I'm getting the following Fatal Error and Notice when I try to access the endpoint on my browser:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Slim\App::$response in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php on line 47 - the first setStatus
```

and

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setStatus() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php on line 47
```

On the same line. Any idea on what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following code?

**Details**

- You have `$app = new \Slim\App();` twice. It is not right.
- You don't need the `$app` variable inside your code. The variable `$response` has the instance to the `Response` object.

PHP

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/getPoiInitialList', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    try 
    {
        $db = getDB();

        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wikivoyage_pois LIMIT 50");

        $sth->execute();
        $poiList = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if($poiList) {

            $response->setStatus(200);
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            echo json_encode($poiList);
            $db = null;

        } else {
            throw new PDOException('No records found.');
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $response->setStatus(404);
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

Comment: With your code, I eliminated the Notice, but I'm still getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method Slim\Http\Response::setStatus().

Comment: Claudio, please, change the code $app->response()->setStatus(404); to $app->response->setStatus(404);

Comment: Claudio, actually the statusCode 200 is the DEFAULT. You don't need set status Code 200. There is a URL (docs) which show how you change the status code ( http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html ) . The status Code 404 for NOT_FOUND page will be raised automatically when some ROUTE does not match the routes you configured.

Comment: @ValdekJunior In this case the 404 code should be returned intentionally e.g. when no records are found. The automatism for non existent routes will not help here.

Answer (score 0):

With Slim 3 you will not call `$response->setStatus(200);` anymore. Like *Valdek* already mentioned status 200 is the default so there's no need to set it again.

To return another status code (like in your catch branch) you have to use the `withStatus` method:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/getPoiInitialList', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    try 
    {
        [...]
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $response->withStatus(404, $e->getMessage());
    }
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```